# Appropriate regression test apart from MLR for crime data?

Tags: statistics, regression, quantile

thanks in advance. I'm looking to run some statistical methods to find the correlation of crime rates to crime factors. I know about MLR, which is pretty simple to run in SPSS, but what are the other appropriate tests that can be run on this type of data? I've scaled the crime numbers to the population for each year, and converted every factor data to rates. I'd ideally like to run something in SPSS, however if needs be I could use R. So far I've looked at hierarchical and stepwise regression in SPSS, and quantile regression in R. Any other suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'd focus solely on the linear regressions for now. They're the easiest to run and interpret, but that does not mean they are trivial. You can learn a lot about your data through these regressions alone. Is there a reason you need a quantile regression? Or a mixture model?

Comment: @Greg It's for a project im doing and im looking to run a different type of regression. I've been looking at Poisson regression too, but not sure how to format the data appropriately. I've got count data and calculated rates too. Do you think it would be ok to use 'per 100,000' data as count data? So I could convert the crime rates to crime per 100,000, convert unemployment rate to unemployment per 100,000, etc, and use those as count data?

Comment: In general, converting variables to a per-capita format (or in your case per 100,000) is a good idea. No, I would not treat the data as count data. Treaing statistics like the crime rate as continuous is, I'd suspect, perfectly fine.